# why $E = X \setminus \{ x: \chi_E (x) < \frac{1}{2} \}?$

Tags: measure-theory

In the following proof, I have a confusion in the last line here.

> *Prove that the characteristic function of a set $E$ is measurable $\iff$ E is measurable.* 
> **Proof:** Suppose that $E$ is a measurable set in a measure space $X$. If $\alpha \le 0$, then $\{x:\chi_E(x)<\alpha\}=\phi$, a measurable set. If $\alpha>1$, then $\{x:\chi_E(x)>\alpha\}=X$, a measurable set. Finally, if $0< \alpha \le 1$, then $\{x:\chi_E(X)<\alpha\}=X\backslash E$, a measurable set. We conclude that $\chi_E$ is a measurable function. 
> Suppose that $\chi_E$ is a measurable function. Then $\textbf{$E=X\backslash\{x:\chi_E(x)<1/2\}$}$ is a measurable set.

**My attempt** : Here its given that $\{ x: \chi_E (x) < \alpha \} = X \setminus E$ where $0 <\alpha \le 1$

According to my thinking   $\{ x: \chi_E (x) < \alpha \} =  E$ where $0 \le \alpha < 1$

Im not getting  why $E = X \setminus \{ x: \chi_E (x) < \frac{1}{2} \}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\chi_E(x) \ge 1/2$, i means that $\chi_E(x) \ge 1/2$, i.e. $\chi_E(x) =1$ and $x \in E$.

Conversely if $x \in E$ then $\chi_E(x)=1$, $\chi_E(x) \ge 1/2$ and $\chi_E(x) \ge 1/2$.

Remember that the characteristic map only takes $0$ or $1$ for values.

Answer (score 1):

$\chi_E$ takes only two values $0$ and $1$. So $\chi_E(x) \geq \frac 1 2$ iff $\chi_E(x)=1$ iff $x \in E$. Thus $x \in E$ iff it is not true that  $\chi_E(x) <\frac 1 2 $.